# ruby jekyll theme can not found error problem

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-theme

today I'm tried to make git blog
but during initial setting I have error of jekyll theme cannot found error on github
I tried to solve this problem but even a bundle install can't help me.
please help me....ㅠㅠ

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRUla.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LvNM.png)
error log

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:84:in `rescue in gemspec': The minimal-mistakes-jekyll theme could not be found. (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:81:in `gemspec'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:19:in `root'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:12:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `new'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `configure_theme'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:55:in `config='
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:23:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-223/bin/github-pages:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-223/bin/github-pages:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `<main>'
```

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'minimal-mistakes-jekyll' (>= 0) among 157 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/github/home/.gem/ruby/2.7.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0:/usr/local/bundle', execute` gem env`for more information from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in`to_spec'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:986:in `find_by_name' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:82:in` gemspec'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:19:in `root' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:12:in` initialize'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `new' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in` configure_theme'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:55:in `config=' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:23:in` initialize'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in` process'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-223/bin/github-pages:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in` block in execute'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in` execute'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go' from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in` program'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-223/bin/github-pages:6:in `<top (required)>' from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in` load'
from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `'
Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /github/workspace/./_config.yml
Theme: minimal-mistakes-jekyll
github-pages 223 | Error:  The minimal-mistakes-jekyll theme could not be found.

Comment: Can you suggest a method to reproduce?

Comment: sorry, I just sloved this problem  a part of setting of config file has a problem.